# Truth in Aquinas metaphysics

Tags: metaphysics, ontology, truth, aquinas

From what I'm reading, Aquinas distinguished truth in two senses:

Ontological truth: It's the adaptation(adequation ?) of the 'created being' to God's understanding, whereby it fulfils that for which it was ordained according to God's Intelligence. When this happens, we say that the created thing is true. Ex: True Man.

Logical truth: It's the adaptation(adequation ?) of man's understanding to the being of the created thing. In this relation, contrary to the ontological  truth, no real relation is created when something is understood by man, i.e. a dependence of the being on the man's understanding, but just a 'logical relation'/'relation of reason' is created. In fact it is man's understanding which is dependent on the being of the thing, and not the other way around.

My question is what is this adaptation/adequation? How does it operate ?

Comment: To understand more what the adequation (i.e., *relation*) of intellect and thing is in truth, maybe John of St. Thomas, the real master of *relation*, would help. John of St. Thomas basically founded modern semiotics (cf. [this](https://carbon.ucdenver.edu/~mryder/deely/basics)), the study of sign (relation). Maybe [this article](http://www.pdcnet.org/newscholas/content/newscholas_1979_0053_0001_0096_0106) would help.

Comment: @Geremia  +1 Thanks for the resources ;)